# If first post, style differently — Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, posts

I need the first post that was ever posted to be styled differently. Is there a way that I can see if the post is first, and then change its contents? I currently have a `div` in all my posts. This needs to be replaced with different `div`.

Apparently the following piece of code can help, but I'm not sure how to implemenet it:

`<?php if (have_posts()) : $postCount = 1; while (have_posts()) : $postCount++; ?>`

I'm new with WordPress so not entirely sure how this could work?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about basic understanding of programming concepts

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Append following codes after yours:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : $postCount = 1; while (have_posts()) : $postCount++; ?>

<?php if($postCount == 2) { ?>
  // SOMETHING TO DO WITH FIRST POST
<?php } else { ?>
  // SOMETHING TO DO WITH ALL OTHER POSTS
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Would I put any after code the first `if` statement, if I wanted to change the divs completely?

Comment: @tmyie updated with `FIRST POST` and `OTHER POSTS` area

Comment: Okay, here's my code as a result of your answer: http://pastebin.com/pjDnXJU9 I've changed the divs `up` and `down`.  Unfortunately, I get an error?

Comment: @tmyie Great! What problem now?

Comment: Here's my entire index.php: http://pastebin.com/TZ5DJghe (It's small). For some reason there's an error on get_footer() at the bottom. There wasn't an error before the `if posts` alteration?

Comment: You forgot end if, replace `<?php endwhile; ?>` with `<?php endwhile; endif; ?>`

Comment: Ah yes, thanks. For some reason the entire code is still not working: http://herbert-theme.info/. I was hoping to see the first post styled differently, and then all the others the same.

Comment: Where area is not working?

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. If you revisit the page, it is displaying the *latest* post differently, it needs to the the *oldest* .

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35920/discussion-between-tmyie-and-bora)

Comment: I guess, this is about `css`

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : $postCount = 0; while (have_posts()) : $postCount++; ?>
```

The above piece of code will create a `$postCount` variable and increment it every time *The Loop* loops. Note that I've changed it to start at 0 instead of 1.

We now have the post count in `$postCount` variable. We just need to find the first post and apply the styles to that post.

Normally, you'll have something like this:

```
<div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
```

Change that to:

```
<div <?php if($postCount == 1) { ?>class="YourSpecialClass"<?php } 
else { ?>class="post"<?php } ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
```

The above code will check if the `$postCount` is `1` (first post), and then add the `class="YourSpecialClass"` part as its `<div>` attribute.

A better readable version:

```
<?php if($postCount == 1) { ?>

    //the first post -- style it

<?php } else { ?>

    //other posts -- proceed normally

<?php } ?>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: At the moment I do not have a post `the_ID`, I've just got `the_content()` and `the_title()`. Would that alter the solution?

Comment: @tmyie: no, it won't. That was just an example.

Comment: You've got `$postCount == 2`, to affect all posts after one, would that be `$postCount => 1` ? :)

Comment: @tmyie see the updated answer. I've changed the `$postCount` variable to start at 0 and then have added a better readable version of the if-else block so you get a better idea.

Comment: Thanks! And I would place this within the standard `<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>` loop?

Comment: @tmyie: that's exactly where this piece of code needs to be added ;)