# How to show first post differently from other posts?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I created the design that will be used to show first post differently from the others. It's not that easy because the first post needs to be in his own div id, which is completely different from the other posts.

Here is the code I currently use in wordpress php:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<!-- Begin Content -->

<div id="content-wide">
  <div class="post">

    <div class="imgwide" style="background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 60%, rgba(0,0,0,0.8)), url(<?php echo catch_that_image() ?>); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 100%; background-position: center;">

      <div class="p-heading">
        <h1>
          <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
          </a>
        </h1>
        <div class="p-content">
          Excerpt text of the first post goes here but php the_excerpt doesnt work for this wide paragraph
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<div id="content-a">

  <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
  <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  <div class="post">
    <div class="imgdiv"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><img src="<?php echo catch_that_image() ?>" width="250"></a></div>
    <div class="p-heading">
      <h1>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
          <?php the_title(); ?>
        </a>
      </h1>
    </div>

    <div class="p-content">
      <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="p-info">
      <?php the_time('j.m.Y') ?> |
      <?php the_category(', '); ?> | <img src="http://www.virmodrosti.com/wp-content/uploads/comments.png" alt="Komentarji" width="26" height="12">
      <?php $totalcomments = get_comments_number(); echo $totalcomments; ?>
    </div>

  </div>

  <?php endwhile; ?>
```

and here is my site url http://www.virmodrosti.com/zdravje/
All I want is that first post isn't displayed twice, but is only moved to the wide post design. The big post is in content-wide. Let me know how to do that. Thank you.

Comment: you just need a simple `if` statement

Comment: I'm not familiar with WordPress and the PHP methods involved but it seems that if you can try adding something along the lines of `<?php if( this_post != first_post ) : ?> [POST CONTENTS HERE] <?php endif; ?>` in your `while` loop. (in other words, add an `if` statement like @cmorrissey suggested)

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18357231/if-first-post-style-differently-wordpress

Comment: Tried many things but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to add a counter that starts in zero and increment it inside your while loop, then use if else statement to check the value of counter if zero display the first post else the other posts.

**EDITED**

```
    <?php $counter = 0; ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php if($counter == 0) { ?>
            <div id="content-wide">
                <div class="post">
                    <div class="imgwide" style="background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 60%, rgba(0,0,0,0.8)), url(<?php echo catch_that_image(); ?>); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 100%; background-position: center;">
                        <div class="p-heading">
                            <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
                            <div class="p-content">
                                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if($counter > 0) { ?>
            <div class="post">
                <div class="imgdiv"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><img src="<?php echo catch_that_image() ?>" width="250"></a></div>
                <div class="p-heading">
                    <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1></div>
                <div class="p-content">
                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="p-info">
                    <?php the_time('j.m.Y') ?> |
                    <?php the_category(', '); ?> | <img src="http://www.virmodrosti.com/wp-content/uploads/comments.png" alt="Komentarji" width="26" height="12">
                    <?php $totalcomments = get_comments_number(); echo $totalcomments; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php $counter ++; ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: I tried that and received blank page, don't know why. I did exactly as specified.  I don't know if two different div id's for first post and the rest  posts fight with each other or because php if statements are located before div id where there are no html entries or something. Even if I add another id wrapper so that the code is inside the wrapper, it doesnt show first post, but only all together. Without this entry `<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>` the page doesnt load, just returns empty page.

Comment: Have included your html inside the if else statement?

Comment: yes they are included in archive.php which applies for virmodrosti.com/zdravje/

Comment: kindly enable error reporting on your wp-config file so we could see the errors that causing it

Comment: error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true);

Comment: I added these entries to wp-config.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146820/discussion-between-techuser-and-penandpapers).